# Error with PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email

I'm having an error trying to send mail with PHP using the `mail()` function. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\strawman\addstudent.php on line 265..
```

Comment: duplicate of [php send mail code not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104555/php-send-mail-code-not-working), [etc.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+sendmail_from+not+set+in+php.ini)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending a mail, a `From` header (i.e. the address from which the mail is sent) has to be set.

This can be set either :

- setting a value for [**`sendmail_from`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-from) in your `php.ini` file *(on windows)*
- or passing a `From` header to the [**`mail`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function -- in the fourth parameter.

The message you posted indicates you've done none of those -- and that you must do at least one, to specify a `From` header.

Quoting the Note in the "*additional_headers*" section of the manual page of [**`mail()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) :

> When sending mail, the mail must
> contain a `From` header. 
> This can
> be set with the `additional_headers`
> parameter, or a default can be set in
> `php.ini`.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an
> error message similar to `Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing.` 
> The `From` header sets
> also `Return-Path` under Windows.

Comment: can you tell me steps on how to do one of those?

Comment: Well, edit your `php.ini` file to set the `sendmail_from` directive ;; or pass a `From` header to the `mail()` function *(see the examples in the manual -- Example #2 has a `From` header)*